# Null pointer Exception on load with Apache Axis2 Java RPCServiceClient

Tags: java, apache, apache-axis

We are trying to access an RPC style webservice using Apache Axis2 framework.. It works well on normal load conditions.. However we could see random null pointer exceptions on slightly increased load.. Below is the trace..

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext.needPropertyDifferences(AbstractContext.java:239)
>           at org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext.setProperty(AbstractContext.java:202)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.obtainHTTPHeaderInformation(HTTPSenderImpl.java:394)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.processResponse(HTTPSenderImpl.java:490)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.handleResponse(HTTPSenderImpl.java:311)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.sendViaPost(HTTPSenderImpl.java:213)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:121)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:403)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:234)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431)
>           at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399)
>           at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
>           at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)

There are few issues logged on the same which are related to Axis2 with ESB..

http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/ESB-Getting-random-NullPointerException-on-Operation-Client-during-Connector-Integration-Tests-td93294.html

But are there any solutions for a pure Java client which uses Axis2?

Code snippet of our implementation below..

```
RPCServiceClient sender = new RPCServiceClient();
MessageContext reqMessageContext = new MessageContext();
OperationClient opClient = sender
                .createClient(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);
        reqMessageContext.setEnvelope(buildRequestSoapEnvelope());
reqMessageContext.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS,
                headers);
opClient.addMessageContext(reqMessageContext);
        opClient.execute(true);

        MessageContext responseMessageContx = opClient
                .getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
```

Any solution or hint would be appreciated.. And we use 1.7.0 version of Axis2 libraries